# Записывание строками в файл

Tags: c#, файлы, io

Как записать в файл данные строками?
Например, пользователь ввёл 101. Оно пишется в первую строку. Далее, пользователь ввёл 86, записывается во вторую строку. И так далее. Подскажите пожалуйста. C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну например:

```
int count = 0;
while (count < 10)
{

    Console.Write(" Enter your string: ");
    string myString = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("You are writing: " + myString);
    File.AppendAllText("fileone.txt", myString + Environment.NewLine);

    count++;
}
```

Где `count < 10` можно заменить на `true`, а выход из цикла сделать например так:

```
if (myString.Contains("exit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Например так

```
string appendText = "Привет всем " +  Environment.NewLine;
File.AppendAllText(@"c:\dir\file.txt", appendText, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Тут получается файл ресурс открывается, сразу же записывается в него необходимый текст и ресурс освобождается.

В случае логирования возможно лучше использовать `FileStream` в сочетании с `StreamWriter` для потокового вывода в файл. То есть можно будет записывать много операций, и потом за раз записать их в файл пакетом `Flush`.

```
using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(@"D:\note.dat", FileMode.Append)))
{
   streamWriter.WriteLine("line1");
   streamWriter.WriteLine("line2");
   streamWriter.WriteLine("line3");
   streamWriter.Flush();
}
```

Comment: При использовании `using` `Flush` не нужен же.

Comment: @VladD в данном случае да, но если во время жизни самого Writer-а будет много операций, и нужно будет ускорить их вывод в файл, то можно использовать `Flush`

Comment: @VladD может быть writer всегда открытый до момента закрытия программы например... хотя сейчас подумал что возможно это и не очень красиво будет.

Comment: Ну, если и правда файл открыт длительное время, то имеет смысл делать Flush время от времени, да.